# Symfony 3.3 - linking to bootstrap.min.css

Tags: php, css, symfony, twitter-bootstrap-3

After investing quite some time on this problem I still cannot get this to work. In my base.html.twig file I link to the bootstrap.min.css file, located at css/bootstrap.min.css inside the web directory, as follows:

```
{% block stylesheets %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" />
{% endblock %}
```

I then extend the base.html.twig file in my template files, when I navigate to any of these files I get the following error message:

```
> Request URL:http://example/css/bootstrap.min.css
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 Not Found
```

I'm at a loss as to what I'm doing wrong here! Any help would be appreciated.

base.html.twig file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

    <title>{% block title %}Welcome!{% endblock %}</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    {% block stylesheets %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{ asset('favicon.ico') }}" />
    {% endblock %}
  </head>

  <body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Todo List</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/todo/create">Add todo</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          {% block body %}{% endblock %}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.container -->
    {% block javascripts %}
    {% endblock %}
  </body>
</html>
```

The index.html.twig file:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
/INDEX
{% endblock %}
```

My server config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "/xampp/htdocs/symfony/todolist/web/app_dev.php"
ServerName todolist
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: can you post your extended file?

Comment: Hi @Arcv - i've include the extra info. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are you able to retrieve anything from the web dir at all? Could be the server config issue

Comment: @StasParshin no, I'm noticing that even the default symfony favicon.ico is not rendering.

Comment: Can you post your server config?

Comment: @StasParshin, I've added the config info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your Apache config seems to be what prevents you from accessing those files. Use the following version instead:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName todolist
    DocumentRoot /xampp/htdocs/symfony/todolist/web
    <Directory /xampp/htdocs/symfony/todolist/web>
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Check out this page for more info: https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html